# C# and flags/bit tests - "Except if" - ... how to?

Tags: c#

Messy title, but am feeling the veins in my brain snap in vain while trying to find a "pretty" (=readable & easily maintainable) way to figure out a way to do something like this in simple terms:

```
[Flags]
enum SomeFlags {
    _unset_ = 0,
    SomeFlag = 1 << 1,
    ExceptionalFlag = 1 << 16,
}
private SomeFlags someenum = SomeFlags._unset_;

...

int times = 1;
while(times > 0)
{
     times--;
     ...
     rnd_num = /*make random number in range X to Y*/ fooRandom();
     ...
     if (rnd_num <= arbitrary_const &&
          ( !someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag)
            [[except if]]
            somenum.HasFlag(Flags.ExceptionalFlag) )
     )
     {
        /* do stuff if numeric condition matches, AND someenum does
          -not- contain SomeFlag, EXCEPT if someenum has -also-
          ExceptionalFlag set alongside SomeFlag */
     }
     else if (...yaddayadda...)
     ...
     else {
         times++;
         someenum |= SomeFlags.ExceptionalFlag;
         continue;
     }
     break;
}
```

Maybe?:

```
if ( /* some_numeric_condition == */ true &&
    (!someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) ||
      someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag | Flags.ExceptionalFlag) ) )
{ /* foobar */ }
```

Is there any "simpler" way to express such?
Just clearing my mind, as that sort of test's buried behind/in pretty lots of code and I'm not familiar with 'unit testing' stuff yet.

Truth table which is sought for:

```
SomeFlag    SomeFlag|ExceptionalFlag  True?
   0           0                      true
   1           0                      false
   0           1                      false
   1           1                      true
```

edit: clarifying a little (I hope) - the if stuff is within a loop, in this particular case... and conditions change.

edit2: edited for truth table sought... And mucked that up, so - another #3 go!

Comment: I can't make out what logic you want from your description. Give us a truth table to show exactly when (under the 8 combinations for the numeric condition, "SomeFlag condition and the "ExceptionalFlag" condition) you want to take the action.

Comment: Based on your new truth table, your simply want to check `SomeFlag|ExceptionalFlag`.

Comment: @Rob Yea, mucked up the table... never tried truth tables XD... Fixed now.

Comment: You'll need to separate the logic out here, typically you wouldn't put `SomeFlag | ExceptionFlag` as a column. Just put `ExceptionalFlag`. We're not interested in operations in truth tables; we're interested only in inputs and outputs. The operations come from our observations of the table. One thing to note though, the third row will never happen. SomeFlag cannot be 0 and *also* have `SomeFlag | ExceptionFlag` be non-zero. Remember that `HasFlag(A | B) = HasFlag(A) & HasFlag(B)`. Hence we can't have `!HasFlag(A) & (HasFlag(A) & HasFlag(B))` ever evaluate to true

Comment: To help; there are only four possible questions. 1. What happens when `SomeFlag` is set and `ExceptionalFlag` is not set? 2 What happens when `SomeFlag` is not set and `ExceptionalFlag` is not set? 3 What happens when `SomeFlag` is set and `ExceptionalFlag` is set? 4 What happens when `SomeFlag` is not set and `ExceptionalFlag` is set?

Comment: @Rob 1) not executed. 2) executed. 3) executed. 4) not executed.

Comment: @Scre In that case, the truth table looks like the one in my answer, except the second line (`0 1 = 1`) becomes `0 1 = 0`. Now note that the *only* truths are when the flags are both not set, or both set. Thus, your code can be `if (A == B)` but perhaps that's not very clear as to the intention. You can be verbose and write `if ((A && B) || (!A && !B))` which does make your intention clear. Or, you can leverage it mathematically and use [XNOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate) - `if (!(A XOR B))` - note the truth table in the wiki matches yours

Comment: @Rob uh... that makes sense, and the table in wiki seems just right. Now I tho can't wrap my mind around how to do XOR with HasFlag, or should I just drop HasFlag altogether and deal with the raw numbers (enum "names") instead?

Comment: You'd apply the XOR to the result of HasFlag. For example, `if (!(someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) ^ someenum.HasFlag(Flags.ExceptionalFlag)))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132803/discussion-between-scre-and-rob).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a shorter equivalent to the code you already have, since that does seem to match your description, you could try

```
!(someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) && !someenum.HasFlag(Flags.ExceptionalFlag))
```

It comes across as

> unless `SomeFlag` is set and `ExceptionalFlag` is not set

as opposed to your original

> if `SomeFlag` is not set, or both flags are set

It's not really much shorter or clearer, it's just a different way of looking at it.

Comment: Well, the goal is to do stuff "if flag is not set unless another-flag is also set". So I guess there's no 'cleaner' way to express it than what's up there :\

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet:

```
(!someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) 
    || someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag | Flags.ExceptionalFlag) )
```

Turns out to be exactly equivelant to:

```
!someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) || someenum.HasFlag(Flags.ExceptionalFlag)
```

There's no need to specify that `SomeFlag` is set - as we've already proved it's not if we enter the second check.

Here's the truth table:

```
SomeFlag  ExceptionalFlag   Expected Result
0         0                 1
0         1                 1
1         0                 0
1         1                 1
```

Comment: Err... except, that this doesn't hold true - there's in reality dozens of Enums in the list. And merely checking if ExceptionalFlag is true, does *not* suffice.

Comment: @Scre The existence of other flags has no impact on the above check or your example snippet. This will logically produce the exact same result as your snippet

Comment: uh, no - it doesn't. `!X||Y` is what yours does, and that's not desired. I need `!X||(X|Y)`

Comment: @Scre Could you show me an input for which `(!someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) || someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag | Flags.ExceptionalFlag))` produces a different result from `!someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag) || someenum.HasFlag(Flags.ExceptionalFlag)`?

Comment: @Scre Logically, if `!someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag)` *fails*, then `SomeFlag` must be set. Thus it's superfluous to check `Flags.SomeFlag | Flags.ExceptionalFlag` rather than just `ExceptionalFlag`. Again, please show me an input which produces different results.

Comment: @Rob This is (also) my answer with De Morgan's law... I like it! Don't know how I missed that...

Comment: @Rawling Indeed! :)

Comment: @Scre While that's true - order of operations matters not here. If you look at the table, you can see the result is *always* true whenever `ExceptionFlag` is true. This will work in any language (that I know of) regardless of the order of operations. Reversing the check will work as well. `someenum.HasFlag(Flags.ExceptionalFlag) || !someenum.HasFlag(Flags.SomeFlag)`. Sometimes when defining a guard it may *appear* as though extra checks are needed. However, many times we can logically remove many of the terms. Hence I find truth tables a very useful tool when trying to simply logical checks :)

Comment: @Rob yea, works fine and dandy when doing stuff with plain numbers. But e.g. Ruby the order of execution "Depends(TM)" on number of sun spots... woe you if one of the checks was not properly braced to enforce order and happened to be a null call.

Comment: Edited for truth table sought.